# ATR is change automatically after two reset

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I have a *JCOP V2.4.2 r3* Java Card. When I insert it in my *ACR38* reader and send two consecutive ATR request with OpenSC-Tool, I receive two different ATR! Is that OK?

Look:

```java
CommandLine> OSC.exe -a
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
3b:f0:13:00:00:81:31:fe:45:e8

CommandLine> OSC.exe -a
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
3b:f9:13:00:00:81:31:fe:45:4a:43:4f:50:32:34:32:52:33:a2
```

If I repeat my request without delay, I will receive the second ATR again and again :

```java
CommandLine> OSC.exe -a
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
3b:f9:13:00:00:81:31:fe:45:4a:43:4f:50:32:34:32:52:33:a2

CommandLine> OSC.exe -a
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
3b:f9:13:00:00:81:31:fe:45:4a:43:4f:50:32:34:32:52:33:a2

CommandLine> OSC.exe -a
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
3b:f9:13:00:00:81:31:fe:45:4a:43:4f:50:32:34:32:52:33:a2
```

But if I wait about 1 minutes (and don't remove the card from the reader), and then request for ATR again, I receive the first short ATR :

```java
CommandLine> OSC.exe -a
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
3b:f9:13:00:00:81:31:fe:45:4a:43:4f:50:32:34:32:52:33:a2

// Waiting about 1 minutes while card is inserted in the reader.
CommandLine> OSC.exe -a
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
3b:f0:13:00:00:81:31:fe:45:e8

//Requesting ATR again and without delay.
CommandLine> OSC.exe -a
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
3b:f9:13:00:00:81:31:fe:45:4a:43:4f:50:32:34:32:52:33:a2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the mentioned reader my best guess is, that you experience the difference between a **cold reset** and a **warm reset**, see ISO 7816-3.

But since the only difference is, that in the short version no historical bytes are provided and in the long the 9 historical bytes indicate "JCOP242R3", this is surely of minor importance.

Comment: Yep. There are separate EEPROM locations for the cold and warm reset for JCOP cards. Sometimes the cold reset is used for more conservative settings, if I'm not mistaken. Usually though, the two are the same.